# Numerical services appearing in cmd

Tags: windows, service, cmd

I am receiving hundreds of numerical services, my anti virus is removing the associated programs. Is there anyway that I can remove all services that contain numbers? I am able to delete them one by one with *sc delete*. Is there anyway to remove them all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but as it happens there wouldn't be enough room there.

> Is there anyway that I can remove all services that contain numbers?

You do recognize that there are legit services that contain numbers?

Here is a dump from my system that does *indeed* show you how to "find all services with numbers in their name":

```
 C:\> powershell
 PS> Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "\d+" } | Select-Object { $_.Name }
```

That outputs the following (truncated for brevity) list of services that are all legit and **you wouldn't want to delete them!**

```
clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32
clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_64
clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32
clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64
FontCache3.0.0.0
...
W32Time
W3SVC
```

To prevent copy/paste without further consideration, here is what you would need to replace the `Select-Object { ... }` above with **if you are really sure you want to delete all such services!**

```
Select-Object { sc.exe delete $_.Name }
```

Again **doing this might render your system totally unusable**.

If possible, you could further [refine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) the pattern above (`\d+`) to really only select those services you mean and first run the command above that only prints their names. If you are 100% sure you didn't get any false positives, you could substitute the last `Select-Object` part with the one calling `sc.exe delete`.

If you are really dealing with some sort of virus or malware infection here, it might be actually better to rebuild the machine from scratch. YMMV.

Comment: This problem is on a whole network, the virus is being stopped by several programs, but it is still creating numerical services. 
we have rebuilt several computers but the Trojan virus is saving itself to rom. we have software that removes it from rom. Do you know if there are any tools that can be used to remove kryptik, emotek, dridix

Comment: No, I don't. You may want to ask a separate question for that. Best on https://superuser.com/, because that would not be "programming related", which is the requirement here on SO.